# reflected XSS : request.getParameter

Tags: jsp, xss

An audit done recently on an application revealed an XSS Reflected vulnerability:

The user controlled input on the parameter idPage is passed directly to the rendered web page as you can see in the source code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="idPage"
       value="<%=(request.getParameter("idPage") == null) ? "" : request.getParameter("idPage")%>">
```

What can I do to resolve that issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `idPage` parameter otherwise an attacker can spam the internet with links like this:

```
http://example.com/reward.jsp?idPage=%22%3E%3Cscript%3Esteal(document.cookie)%3C/script%3E
```

Where `%22%3E%3Cscript%3Esteal(document.cookie)%3C/script%3E` is equal to:

```
"><script>steal(document.cookie)</script>
```

And your script would render a page like this and most likely execute some malicious script:

```
<input type="hidden" name="idPage"
       value=""><script>steal(document.cookie)</script>">
```

Give or take (you may need some extra encoding but that's roughly what the attack would look like)